# Google Places API number of ratings

Tags: google-places-api

I am working on a team project. We need the number of ratings / reviews. Looking into the API I could not find the information. Questions are:

- Is there any way to get these information?
- How were the number of reviews calculated (how many third parties apps are involving?)

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Details requests currently return an undocumented `user_ratings_total` property.  I don't believe they provide the number of reviews.

Edit: It seems that this property is no longer returned.  Thanks to Evan for noticing this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Pushbit. I called a GET and could not see the user_rating_total in any POI I received. Could you please give me a coordinator example where I can see this information? Many thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're sending a search request.  `user_ratings_total` is only available in details responses (where you use the `reference` from a search result).  Check the official docs for the different types of requests you can send and the responses that you will receive.

Comment: FYI - Looks like that property was removed a couple of days ago. Hopefully, it will be officially added back.

Comment: Two related issues on google: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9824 and
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3484